# fetch gives response Unexpected token ] in JSON

Tags: fetch-api

The JSON file is local, in public where it is accessible. The error references the text found in the JSON file where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check for commas after the last item in arrays within the JSON file. Fetch doesn't like these, even if online JSON checkers give it a pass.

`{"documents": [ {"important":"something"}, ]`

```
                                        ^NO
```